# Difference between using Matrix directly and Android View?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

If I understand it correctly, `View` (`ImageView`, `TextView`, …) use internally a `Matrix` to display its content.

But, for example, `View` has the methods `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` to change its scale, but one could also scale its internal Matrix too.

And there's also the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, that allows changing its height and width.

So, are `View` methods internally transforming the `Matrix` the same way as if doing it directly, or is there any difference between using one or the other? I couldn't find much information about this.

Comment: Have you read the source code? How else you got to the point where you realized views use a matrix to transform it's drawing area. Methods that set scale, rotation etc. essentially just save new value, clear some caches call invalidate then matrix is recalculated. If you only reflect and modify internal matrix without those invalidations you will encounter some glitches or your modifications will get overriden when view itself revalidates the matrix.

Comment: I've done some research. So is it true then that its the same method?

Comment: By "using Matrix directly" I meant getting the Matrix from the View using the #getMatrix() method or similar, not using any reflection or workarounds.

Comment: From my understanding `getMatrix()` is intended as read only because as I mentioned earlier any changes you apply to it will be wiped out whenever view decides it needs to be invalidated.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for your help. Now I realize that my understanding of `Matrix` was wrong. I was asking this because I needed to transform and scale an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, and I wanted to know if there were any disadvantages in using one or the other.
I was trying to change the `View` size and, while it works without rotation, if I rotate the view then it acted weirdly. In the end I figured out a workaround to fix it.

Comment: In case anyone reading this needs it, my problem was that I wanted to scale rotated views consistently. Here's the workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69931599/11880323